# Which graphics applications work with Intuos3? MacBook Pro laptop, Running Mac 10.14.6

Tags: macbook-pro

I just purchased a used Intuos3 from our local university auction.  Plugged it into my laptop and everything seemed to work just fine.  The only problem is that I don't have an application that will allow me to draw.  Several programs such as TextEdit and Pages have no problem with the pen controlling the cursor but there is nothing on the page.  LibreOffice Drawing will not work.  I have tried gimp and reset the input devices trying them all, but it does not allow the pen to control the cursor.  I am running out of ideas.  Please send me suggestions of applications/software that might work.

Thank you, NDDonna

Answer (score 1):

Wacom doesn't work as 'plug & play', you will need compatible drivers - see https://www.wacom.com/en-us/support/product-support/drivers